# Rectangle Class (objects) can have two intrinsic parameters length and width. How to write (independent) function to calculate the area?

Tags: scala

Here is the code I have written for Rectangle class.

```
    class Rectangle (l: Double, w: Double) {
        require (l > 0, w > 0)
        val length = l
        val width = w
        def this (l: Double) = this (l, l)
        def setDimensions (l: Double, w: Double) = new Rectangle (l, w)
        def setLength (l: Double) = new Rectangle (l, width)
        def setWidth (w: Double) = new Rectangle (length, w)
    }
```

My question is how to write following functions (independent of Rectangle class) in Scala:

1. Given the length and width calculate the area of the Rectangle
2. Given the length and area calculate the width of the Rectangle
3. Given the width and area calculate the length of the Rectangle
4. Given the Rectangle Object show the length, width and area

This question arose after going through the following paragraph from [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-scala01228/index.html):

> Functional languages get their name from the concept that programs should behave like mathematical functions; in other words, given a set of inputs, a function should always return the same output. Not only does this mean that every function must return a value, but that functions must inherently carry no intrinsic state from one call to the next. This intrinsic notion of statelessness, carried over into the functional/object world to mean immutable objects by default, is a large part of why functional languages are being hailed as the great saviors of a madly concurrent world.

Please note that as Scala beginner, I am trying to grasp the FP part of it.

Comment: @tenshi    My idea of functions was that without creating any Rectangle object only arbitrary values can be given and results can be obtained. For any elaboration, pleae write to me.

Comment: I added another answer... is that what you mean?

Comment: @tenshi    Yes, your second answer is in line with my idea of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for you:

```
case class Rectangle(length: Double, width: Double) {
    require (length > 0, width > 0)

    lazy val area = length * width
    override def toString = s"length: $length, width: $width, area: $area"
}

object Rectangle {
    def fromLength(length: Double) = Rectangle(length, length)
    def fromLengthArea(length: Double, area: Double) = Rectangle(length, area / length)
    def fromWidthArea(width: Double, area: Double) = Rectangle(area / width, width)
    def show(rect: Rectangle) = println(rect)
}

// Usage

Rectangle show Rectangle(2, 3)
Rectangle show Rectangle.fromLength(2)
Rectangle show Rectangle.fromLengthArea(2, 6)
Rectangle show Rectangle.fromWidthArea(3, 6)
```

I can recommend you to always case classes where it's appropriate, especially for classes like `Rectangle`.

`show` method needs to print results, so you can't avoid side-effects in this case. In other words this function is not referentialy transparent. Actually, the whole constructor of `Rectangle` can be considered not referentialy transparent because you are using `require`. You can avoid this by insuring, that `Rectangle` will always receive correct values somewhere outside the class, but you also need to return something, when `Rectangle` class cannot be created because of validation errors. You can use `Option` class for this purpose. Here is little example of this:

```
case class Rectangle private (length: Double, width: Double) {
    lazy val area = length * width
    override def toString = s"length: $length, width: $width, area: $area"
}

object Rectangle {
    def fromLengthWidth(length: Double, width: Double) = 
        validating(length, width)(new Rectangle(length, width))

    def fromLength(length: Double) = validating(length)  {
        new Rectangle(length, length)
    }

    def fromLengthArea(length: Double, area: Double) = validating(length, area) {
        new Rectangle(length, area / length)
    }

    def fromWidthArea(width: Double, area: Double) = validating(width, area) {
        new Rectangle(area / width, width)
    }

    def show(rect: Option[Rectangle]) = println(rect getOrElse "Invalid Rectangle!!!")

    private def validating[R](values: Double*)(fn: => R) = 
        if (values forall (_ > 0)) Some(fn)
        else None   
}

Rectangle show Rectangle.fromLengthWidth(2, 3)
Rectangle show Rectangle.fromLength(0)

// prints:
//    length: 2.0, width: 3.0, area: 6.0
//    Invalid Rectangle!!!
```

As you can see I made constructor private and moved validation in the companion object (which can access private member of the class with the same name). So you can't create invalid rectangle. But important point here, is that even if you provide broken length, you still receive something (in this case it's `None` object which is instance and subclass of `Option` class).

I added `area` method to the class, but you can of course write an independent method or function that calculates area:

```
def area(rect: Rectangle) = rect.length * rect.width
```

or

```
val area = (rect: Rectangle) => rect.length * rect.width
```

I hope this will help you in understanding this topic. If it's still not clear (or my answer does not cover what you actually wanted to know), please don't hesitate and leave a comment.

Comment: @Optimight: you mean area also should be greater than 0? I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is implementation of the functions you described:

```
def area(length: Double, width: Double) = length * width
def length(width: Double, area: Double) = if (width > 0) area / width else 0
def width(length: Double, area: Double) = if (length > 0) area / length else 0
def show(rect: Rectangle) = 
    println(rect.length + ", " + rect.width + ", " + area(rect.length, rect.width))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was curious how to do this with type classes and so I came up with this version, that will not even allow you to compile code with invalid Rectangles. I bet this can be done a little cleaner, but this is what I quickly put together:

```
trait LengthCalc[-A] {
  def length(x: A): Double
}

trait WidthCalc[-A] {
  def width(x: A): Double
}

trait AreaCalc[-A] {
  def area(x: A): Double
}

case class Rectangle[A <: Option[Double], B <: Option[Double], C <: Option[Double]](lengthOpt: A = None, widthOpt: B = None, areaOpt: C = None)
(implicit lengthCalc: LengthCalc[Rectangle[A,B,C]], widthCalc: WidthCalc[Rectangle[A,B,C]], areaCalc: AreaCalc[Rectangle[A,B,C]]) {
  lazy val length = lengthCalc.length(this)
  lazy val width = widthCalc.width(this)
  lazy val area = areaCalc.area(this)
}

implicit object RectLengthCalcFromLength extends LengthCalc[Rectangle[Some[Double], _ <: Option[Double], _ <: Option[Double]]] {
  def length(x: Rectangle[Some[Double], _ <: Option[Double], _ <: Option[Double]]) = x.lengthOpt.get
}

implicit object RectLengthCalcFromWidthAndArea extends LengthCalc[Rectangle[None.type, Some[Double], Some[Double]]] {
  def length(x: Rectangle[None.type, Some[Double], Some[Double]]) = (for {
    area <- x.areaOpt
    width <- x.widthOpt
  } yield (area / width)).get
}

implicit object RectWidthFromWidth extends WidthCalc[Rectangle[_ <: Option[Double], Some[Double], _ <: Option[Double]]] {
  def width(x: Rectangle[_ <: Option[Double], Some[Double], _ <: Option[Double]]) = x.widthOpt.get
}

implicit object RectWidthFromLengthAndArea extends WidthCalc[Rectangle[Some[Double], None.type, Some[Double]]] {
  def width(x: Rectangle[Some[Double], None.type, Some[Double]]) = (for {
    area <- x.areaOpt
    length <- x.lengthOpt
  } yield (area / length)).get
}

implicit object RectAreaFromArea extends AreaCalc[Rectangle[_ <: Option[Double], _ <: Option[Double], Some[Double]]] {
  def area(x: Rectangle[_ <: Option[Double], _ <: Option[Double], Some[Double]]) = {
    x.areaOpt.get
  }
}

implicit object RectAreaFromLengthAndWidth extends AreaCalc[Rectangle[Some[Double], Some[Double], None.type]] {
  def area(x: Rectangle[Some[Double], Some[Double], None.type]) = (for {
    width <- x.widthOpt
    length <- x.lengthOpt
  } yield (width * length)).get
}
```

Here are some example calls:

```
scala> Rectangle(Some(3.),None,Some(4.))
res8: Rectangle[Some[Double],None.type,Some[Double]] = Rectangle(Some(3.0),None,Some(4.0))

scala> res8.width
res9: Double = 1.3333333333333333


scala> Rectangle(Some(3.),None,None)
<console>:25: error: could not find implicit value for parameter widthCalc: WidthCalc[Rectangle[Some[Double],None.type,None.type]]
          Rectangle(Some(3.),None,None)


scala> Rectangle(None, Some(8.), Some(64.))
res10: Rectangle[None.type,Some[Double],Some[Double]] = Rectangle(None,Some(8.0),Some(64.0))

scala> res10.length
res11: Double = 8.0
```